# Find probability in R

Tags: r, function, statistics, probability

I have to find the probability that AFC team wins a game given that they won the game before?

My data looks like:

```
df <- " hometeam    awayteam    result  season
    AFC      BFC          WH       S1
    DFC      AFC          WA       S2
    HFC      BFC          D       S2
    MFC      AFC          WA       S1
    BFC      AFC          L       S3
    DFC      KFC          L       S2
    AFC      DFC          WH       S3"
df <- read.table(text = df, header = TRUE)
```

P(AFC Wins| Previous game won)?

How do I find the count for WW in basic R?

I want to count the instances for WH-WA & WA-WH together(WH-Home Win,WA- Away Win) so here we see 2 instance (Similarly WA-WA, WH-WH).

How do I find the count for each?

Comment: so you mean to count WH and WA probabilties combined? if I get it correctly?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include an expected outcome?

Comment: @JovanGeraldyCandra Yes

Comment: Updated my Answer @Emma Vaze

Answer (score 2):

1. How do I find the count basically in R for individual elements?

If you want to make count for the column results, you can try:

```
table(df$results)

D L W 
1 3 2
```

2. `P(AFC Wins| Previous game won)?`

If you want to calculate conditional probabilities like above, I recommend using Bayesian Belief Network, this Network will compile your data to a detailed probabilities, and then you can make a query request to the network

```
library(bnlearn)
hc_bn_learning <- hc(df) #using hc learners
bbn <- bn.fit(hc_bn_learning, data = df)
cpquery(bbn, event = (result=="W"), evidence = (hometeam=="AFC"))
0.3525641
```

3. If you want to calculate combined probabilities with basic R,

I suppose manipulate table is a direct way to do it: (example to get WA and WH probabilities combined)

```
sum(table(df$result)[which(names(table(df$result)) %in% c("WA","WH"))]) / 
sum(table(df$result))

0.5714286
```

4. If you want to calculate count and probabilties by row wise, given a desired element "WH" to the target element of "WA"

I defined a custom function to do this, so it will be easier to apply to a bigger context

```
row_wise_pattern_count <- function(df, col_search, pattern_search=c(), 
                                   pattern_target=c(), mode="count"){
  row_vector <- df[, which(colnames(df)==col_search)]
  count_pattern <- 0
  for(x in 1:length(row_vector)){
    if(row_vector[x] %in% pattern_search && row_vector[x+1] %in% pattern_target){
      count_pattern <- count_pattern + 1
    }
  }
  if(mode=="count"){
    return(count_pattern) 
  }
  else if(mode=="prob"){
    return(count_pattern / (length(row_vector) - 1))
  }
}
```

This applies like this, when you search for a given WA element for a next WH element to appear in next row, so you can use

```
row_wise_pattern_count(df, "result", pattern_search=c("WA"), pattern_target=c("WH"))
[1] 0
```

when you search "vice versa" for a given WH element for a next WA element to appear in next row, so you can use

```
row_wise_pattern_count(df, "result", pattern_search=c("WH"), pattern_target=c("WA"))
[1] 1
```

you can also set the mode to "prob" to return probability of the sequencial pattern instead of count

```
row_wise_pattern_count(df, "result", pattern_search=c("WH"), pattern_target=c("WA"), mode="prob")
[1] 0.1666667
```

Comment: I'm looking to solve it in basic R. Without the use of libaries.

Comment: I'm looking to count consecutive instances of WL together based on the condition. Not individual counts.

Comment: Instances of WL together do you mean probabilities of win & lose count together?

Comment: You may want to update your question to reflect more accurately what you are looking for.

Comment: @JovanGeraldyCandra This is not what I'm referring to, I want the count of such sequence where in if record 1 has WH the next record has WA and vice versa.

Comment: so you mean to count via rows sequentially? where if WA-WH spotted, it counted incrementally 1 and WH-WA spotted, it counted incrementally by 1?

Comment: Sorry I hardly to get it since the question can be related to kinds of things